# Как сделать разделительную полосу в поле input

Tags: html, css

там где лупа и ввод текста есть полоса вертикальная, как ее сделать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинкой, псевдоэлементами... С исходным кодом было бы понятнее

Comment: картину не добавляю, добавил иконку через fontawesome

Comment: Думаю он имел ввиду слева есть блок с картинкой или вашей иконкой, у нее может быть `border-right`, а правее уже `input`. Но если честно я не знаю других путей сделать это, так что мне интересно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если автору хочется вертикальную полоску внутри инпута, то можно и так:

```css
input{
  background:#f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcde;
  padding:0 0 0 65px;
  height:30px;
}
.input-separator{
  width:1px;
  height:26px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #dcdcde;
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  top:3px;
}
.input-block{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class = "input-block">
      <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Enter you keyword...'/>
      <div class="input-separator"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Единственный вопрос. Почему мы делаем отступ для полосы сверху 3 px? По логике вещей, высота родителя - 30px, отнимаем -26px, получаем 4 пикселя в распоряжения. Сверху 2 и внизу 2(учитывая border родителя будет как раз отступ в 1 px), должно быть `top:2px`, но так прижимается к верхней части и я не пойму почему.

Comment: Родитель в данном случае input-block, его высота 32px (30px - input + 2px - border)

Comment: А, высота изменена рамкой. Окей, спасибо, что-то я притупил...

Answer (score 2):

```css
form,
.form-row {
  position: relative;
}

/* Иконка поиска */
label {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  border-right: 1px solid #afafaf;
}

/* Дополнительные стили для наглядности: */
form {
  padding-right: 100px;
}

/* Кнопка поиск */
input[type="submit"]{
  background: #269dc7;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Поле поиска */
input[type="search"]{
  height: 50px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-right: none;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="s"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><input type="search" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Enter ...">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```